# Find elements in array with the same color and print true if they are next to each other

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit, compare

It somehow works, the way i did it. But i know there should be better and optimized way to do this check for all rows and all colors. If you know any, please share. Thanks

```
  func checkMovesAvailable(){
    var count = 0
    var yellowArray = [0,0,0,0]
    var movesAvailable: Bool = false
    for i in 0..<3{
    square[i, 0]
    if(square.fillColor == SKColor.yellow){
    yellowArray.remove(at: i)
    yellowArray.insert(1, at: i)
    print(yellowArray)

    if yellowArray[0] == yellowArray[1] || yellowArray[1] == yellowArray[2] || 
yellowArray[2] == yellowArray[3] {
    count += 1
    }
    }
    }

    if(count>=2){
    movesAvailable = true
    }
    if(count<=1){
    movesAvailable = false
    }
    print("movesAvailable: \(movesAvailable)")
    }
```

[image: preview]

Comment: In the code above it only works for yellows in the bottom row 0. So if two yellow squares are next to each other then you can move one into another = move is available)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have an array
of `SKShapeNode`s and want to check if any adjacent nodes have the
same fill color. That can simply be done with:

```
func isMoveAvailable(squares: [SKShapeNode]) -> Bool {
    return zip(squares, squares.dropFirst()).contains(where: { $0.fillColor == $1.fillColor })
}
```

Explanation:

- `squares.dropFirst()` returns a sequence of the nodes *without*
  the first element.
- `zip(squares, squares.dropFirst())` returns a sequence with pairs
  of adjacent nodes:

  ```
  (node0, node1), (node1, node2), ...
  ```
- `contains(...)` checks if there is a pair with the same fill color.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you! Any explanation would be great